# stored-proc-outbound-gateway parameter and results handling

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I need to invoke a oracle stored proc based on an incoming message, something like shown below. The incoming message has a method that returns the in parameters but i don't find a way to bind this together.

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway 
            id="dbPollar"
            data-source="someDtaSource"
            request-channel="triggerChannel" 
            reply-channel="loggit"
            stored-procedure-name="somePackage.someProc">                   
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="rowid" direction="IN" type="ROWID"/>
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="error" direction="OUT" type="NVARCHAR"/>
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="mesage" direction="OUT" type="NVARCHAR"/>      
            <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="ref" row-mapper="rowMapper"/>                   
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

The question i have is how to pass the in parameter and how to retrieve the out parameters. Given that we have single reply-channel, how does it work. I would like to generate an output message which wraps the out parameters and has a collection of result rows in reply channel.Please point out to any doc if that contains relevant details. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output message payload is a `Map` of outputs keyed by the parameter name.

Comment: Thanks gary, and how will it take the IN parameter from incoming message?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures . `<int-jdbc:parameter>` comes to the rescue!

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/stored-procedures-oracle